# CSS Attribute conflict, which is supposed to win?

Tags: html, css

If I define a CSS attribute in both a CSS class and inside an element directly, which value ends up being used?

Let's use width as our example

```
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  .a {
   width: 100px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="a" style="width: 200px;"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What should the width of the div be in a browser? (according to the standard, not what happens in practice)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cascading (hence its name) says it's **element's preference** over in-file styles over referenced file styles.

Answer (score 2):

The "style" attribute will trump the class selector.

See the ever useful Selectutorial for a [walkthrough of how conflicting rules are resolved](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_conflict.htm). See also the [CSS2 specification section on specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

Answer (score 1):

The element's style will be used as it has a higher specificity.

The specificity rules:

- element `style`: 1000 points
- id: 100 points
- class: 10 points
- element name (table, div, etc.): 1 point

Examples:

- `.class` is 10 points
- `table.class` is 11 points
- `div#myId.class` is 111 points
- `div` is 1 point

The declaration with the most points will be used. However, you could override styling placed at any level by using `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be 200px. The rule defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) says that if the "if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector" then that's the highest priority/specificity.

Answer (score 1):

the defined value on the element should prevail...

Answer (score 1):

About that question, you can take a look at the specification ; especially section [6.4.3 Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity). Section [6.4.1 Cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) will probably be usefull too.

The "style" attribute is the last one to be declared and the most specific ; so this is the one that should be used.

Comment: It's used because it's the most specific, not because it's the last one declared; knowing which one is the "last" one would only be significant between rules of otherwise-equal specificity.